# Swiping images on a Bootstrap's Carousel doesn´t work on Android Studio WebView

Tags: android, webview, carousel, swipe

I have a PHP page showing some text and a Bootstrap 3.4.1 images Carousel and it works fine using Chrome.

But if I show it on an Android Studio's WebView, the page (with the Carousel) shows ok, but the carousel don't move, don't swipe and the prev/next buttons don't work.

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvContenido"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

Again, the page works OK on Chrome (android and windows)

Help pls

I tried loading the page from an assets folder, loading from a local server URL and a web server URL. Same result.

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvContenido);
//wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/contenido/cursos_1_1.php");
wv.loadUrl("http://172.28.1.153/siiees/contenido/cursos_1_1.php");
wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```